# Very low number of visitors per day

Tags: bug, statistics

Two weeks ago, Mathematics Educators had around 458 visitors per day.  Just a few minutes ago I was surprised to discover that we have only 1 visitors (sic) per day.  (The image below right is what I see on the right side of the main site.)  Refreshing the screen or visiting it again from a different tab doesn't change it.  When I visit the Area 51 page, I see 0 visits per day.  (See the image below left.)

[image: 0 visits/day]

This problem doesn't seem to be unique to Mathematics Educators.  For example, History of Science and Mathematics currently shows 2 visitors per day on its main site.

What's going on here?

Comment: It seems that this has already been reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51) but with no explanation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been fixed.  (See this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311989/177408) on Meta Stack Exchange.)

> We made major changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure a few months back and completely missed that the same GA properties were used to drive the metrics behind Area51 stats and overall site analytics.

Comment: Right now, the Area 51 site for Mathematics Educators shows 753 visits per day.